Find the value of $P(3^5) + Q(3^{10}) +R(3^{15})$
Question: The Polynomials $P(x)$, $Q(x)$, $R(x)$, $S(x)$ satisfy the equation
$$P(x^5)+\frac x 3 Q(x^{10})+\frac{x^2}{3^2}R(x^{15})=\left(1+\frac x3+\frac {x^2}{3^2}+\frac {x^3}{3^3}+\frac {x^4}{3^4}\right)S(x^3)+(3x+2)^2.$$
Find the value of $P(3^5)+Q(3^{10})+R(3^{15}).$
My attempt: I tried writing the degrees of the polynomials as $N_1$, $N_2$, $N_3$, and putting the values and comparing coefficients. But I'm lacking the number of equations. I also tried using the geometric progression formula and finding functions by trial and error.

What is your question? Take a tour instead.

It is recommended your write your question instead of the image using latex and add some of your attempt.

I'm sorry, my first time posting a question. Is it ok now?

SRMC paper, a competition held between IIT Madras and IIT Kanpur

We see the appearance of $\frac{x}{3}$ everywhere. We can simplify the problem with the following substitutions:
$$x = 3y$$
$$P_{3}(y)= P(3^5y)$$
$$Q_{3}(y)= Q(3^{10}y)$$
$$R_{3}(y)= R(3^{15}y)$$
$$S_{3}(y)= S(3^{3}y)$$
The problem becomes:
$$P_{3}(y^5) + y \;Q_{3}(y^{10}) + y^2\;R_{3}(y^{15}) = (1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4)S_{3}(y^3) + (9y + 2)^2$$
which is the following by noting the geometric progression
$$P_{3}(y^5) + y \;Q_{3}(y^{10}) + y^2\;R_{3}(y^{15}) = \frac{y^5-1}{y-1}S_{3}(y^3) + (9y + 2)^2$$
We want to compute: $$P_3(1) + Q_{3}(1) + R_{3}(1)$$

We notice that the coefficient of $S_{3}$ $\;$ (ie. $\frac{y^5-1}{y-1}$) $\;$ vanishes when $y^5 = 1$ with $y\neq 1$. Additionally, the values at which $P_{3}, Q_{3}, R_{3}$ are evaluated for such $y$ become $1$, even as their coefficients do not. Setting $y = z$ where $z^5 = 1$ with $z\neq 1$, our equation becomes:
$$P_{3}(1) + z\;Q_3(1) + z^2Q_{3}(1) = (9z+2)^2$$
We have four such possible $z$ numbers, and they satisfy $1+ z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 = 0$. We must find a linear combination of the four resulting equations that brings the coefficients of $P_{3}, Q_{3}$ and $R_{3}$ to $1.$ Define: $$I(z)= P_{3}(1) + z\;Q_3(1) + z^2Q_{3}(1)$$
and $z_{1}= e^{\frac{2\pi}{5}}$ a fifth root of unity.
We see (using $z_1^5=1$ and $z_{1}^1 + z_{1}^2 + z_{1}^3 + z_{1}^4 = -1$) that
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^4 z_{1}^n \;I(z_{1}^n)\\
=& z_{1}^1 \;I(z_{1}^1) +  z_{1}^2 \;I(z_{1}^2)  +  z_{1}^3 \;I(z_{1}^3) +  z_{1}^4 \;I(z_{1}^4) \\
=& P_3(1)\sum_{n=1}^{4}z_{1}^n 
+ Q_3(1) \sum_{n=1}^{4}z_{1}^{2n}
+ R_3(1) \sum_{n=1}^{4}z_{1}^{3n}\\
=&-1\times(P_3(1) + Q_3(1) +R_3(1)).
\end{align}$$
From this we can compute using $I(z)=(9z+2)^2$ that
$$ 
\begin{align}
&P_3(1) + Q_3(1) +R_3(1) \\
=& -\left(\sum_{n=1}^{4}z_{1}^n(9z_{1}^n+2)^2\right)\\ 
=& -4\sum_{n=1}^{4}z_{1}^n 
- 36\sum_{n=1}^{4} z_{1}^{2n} 
- 81\sum_{n=1}^{4} z_{1}^{3n}\\ 
=& 4 + 36 + 81 = \boxed{121}\end{align}$$

Set $y=\frac x3$. Modulo $1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4$, we have $y^5\equiv1$ hence
$$\begin{align}0&\equiv P(3^5y^5)+yQ(3^{10}y^{10})+y^2R(3^{15}y^{15})-(9y+2)^2\\&\equiv P(3^5)+yQ(3^{10})+y^2R(3^{15})-(9y+2)^2.\end{align}$$
Since the RHS is of degree $<4$, and is divisible by a polynomial of degree $4$, it is the zero polynomial, hence (by evaluation at $1$):
$$P(3^5)+Q(3^{10})+R(3^{15})=(9+2)^2=121.$$

I've not seen this approach before. It seems intuitive, tough I still can't fully follow how we go from results and equalities mod $1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4$ (the mod makes a quotient ring, if I recall), back to results over the whole ring. Can you provide more background info or references?

In any ring $B$, in particular in our ring $B:=A[y]$ (where $A$ can be any commutative ring, not necessarily the field $\Bbb R$), $U\equiv V\bmod W$ is an abbreviation for: $W$ divides $U-V$, i.e. $\exists L\in B,;U-V=LW$. Here, $W=1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4$, $y^5-1=(y-1)W$, hence $\bmod W$ we have $y^5\equiv1$ and therefore, $y^{5k}\equiv1^k=1$ for every $k\in\Bbb N$ hence (by linear combination) $S(y^5)\equiv S(1)$ for every polynomial $S(t)$, like $P(3^5t),Q(3^{10}t^2),R(3^{15}t^3)$. We stay in $B$ and never need to consider the quotient ring $B/(W)$.

Some more explanation for "and therefore, $y^{5k}\equiv1^k=1$": to prove it, you can (for instance) show that if $U_1\equiv V_1$ and $U_2\equiv V_2$ then $U_1U_2\equiv V_1V_2$, and then (by induction) $U_1^k\equiv V_1^k$.

Yes. I can follow the proof now. I guess the main "implicit" theorem used here is: $(a \equiv b) \rightarrow (P(a) \equiv P(b))$ for all polynomials $P$.

Indeed! (for any polynomials $a,b$). The particular case $P(t)=t^k$ was explained in my last comment, and the general case follows by linear combination, like in my second to last comment.

This was such a beautiful argument! (+1)
